# Need instruction for changing onblur to onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, onblur

I'm working on adopting wysiwyg editor SummerNote having a problem with saving as the script utilize "onblur" callback function that I want to turn into on click event.

This is the function saving a page,

```
$(function() {
    var editElements = {};
    $('.editable').summernote({
        airMode: false,
        toolbar: [
            // [groupName, [list of button]]
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['font', ['fontsize', 'color']],
            ['para', ['paragraph']],
            ['insert', ['link','image', 'doc', 'video']], // image and doc are customized buttons
            ['table', ['table']],
            ['misc', ['codeview']],
        ],
        placeholder: 'Click here to enter content.',
        callbacks: {
            onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
                editElements[$(this).attr('id')] = contents;
            },
           /* onBlur: function() {
                if (editElements[$(this).attr('id')]!=undefined) {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var content = editElements[$(this).attr('id')];
                    var target = ($(this).attr('data-target')!=undefined) ? $(this).attr('data-target'):'pages';
                    editElements[$(this).attr('id')] = undefined;
                    $.post("",{
                        fieldname: id,
                        content: content,
                        target: target,
                        token: token,
                    })
                    .done(function() {
                        $("#save").show();
                        $('#save').delay(100).fadeOut(); 
                    });
                }
            } */
        },
    });
});
```

And this is tryout to adopt onblur callback into on click event function with the empty contents return.

```
$(document).on('click','#addsave', function(e){
            editElements[$(this).attr('id')] = contents;
                      if (editElements[$(this).attr('id')]!=undefined) {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var content = editElements[$(this).attr('id')];
                    var target = ($(this).attr('data-target')!=undefined) ? $(this).attr('data-target'):'pages';
                    editElements[$(this).attr('id')] = undefined;
                    $.post("",{
                        fieldname: id,
                        content: content,
                        target: target,
                        token: token,
                    });  
                  }
              });
```

Yet as I've been advised this is not working during mispointing $(this) selector as it refers to the editable content area empty on the click button instance.
So the problems is function reference or selectors as '.editable' is loaded as 'div class editable' - How to convert above 'onblur' callback to button click function? Any advice really appreciated, regards

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a value to the `this` keyword inside a funciton by using the '[Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)' function on it.

I'm assuming there is only one `.editable` element on the page in this code example:

```
// create your event handler
var save = function() {  
    editElements[$(this).attr('id')] = contents;
    if (editElements[$(this).attr('id')]!=undefined) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var content = editElements[$(this).attr('id')];
        var target = ($(this).attr('data-target')!=undefined) ? $(this).attr('data-target'):'pages';
        editElements[$(this).attr('id')] = undefined;
        $.post("",{
            fieldname: id,
            content: content,
            target: target,
            token: token,
        });  
    }
}

// get a reference to the .editable elemement
var that = document.getElementsByClassName('.editable')[0];

// bind it to 'this' in our click event handler
$(document).on('click','#addsave', save.bind(that));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggested solution - thought of bind as well, this your provided script is returning 'undefined' value for the single '.editable' instance, although there are 3 more 'textarea'(removed during test) needed that are actually replaced on the fly by wysiwyg(SummerNote) script to the editable div and that is injecting on blur in textarea and saving as explained. Thank you for proposed option, yet have to examine further and will provide additional information upon.
Regards